# Is there any way that make one intent execute automatically after an intent finished in dialogflow?

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

I create an intent. When the user said I want to find blah blah, this intent will be activated and call the fulfilment to scrape on the Internet to get the useful information. After the information was got, the fulfilment will send the result back to User. 
However, the above process takes about 8s. Hence, I want to add a prompt like "I'm searching, please wait...' before searching the result.

Below is what I want. After the user sends a query, the intent A will be invoked, and say 'I'm searching, please wait for a second...'. After that, (user don't need to say anything) intent B will be triggered automatically and call the fulfilment to scrape on the Internet.

User: I want to find blah blah.

System(intent A): I'm searching, please wait for a second...

System(intent B): Here is what I found blah blah.

Is there any way to trigger intent B automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way,

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function searchresult(agent) {
        agent.add(' wait let me search....')
        search('your key').then(result => {
            agent.add('send result')
        })
    }


    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('search', searchresult);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});



function search(key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // your search query will return either error or result
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(result);
    });
}
```